# I keep getting this error "for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized" how do i resolve it?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a noob to pygame and I keep getting this error "for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized" here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run=True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            run = False
```

How can i resolve this. i have tried changing `pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))` to `pygame.display.get.surface` and that ran into the same error. thank you in advance for any help.
-Kenneth Ayers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```py
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
```

Should be:

```py
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

You are quiting pygame instead of checking for QUIT.

Comment: thank you so much!!! but now pycharm is throwing this error "line 17, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: Remove the brackets after `pygame.QUIT`. It is a constant, not a method call.